# How to add a ProgressBar and a button underneath a marker

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, marker, mapactivity

I would like to add a button and a progress bar underneath every marker in my map. 
Let me show you my map:

[[image: Here you can see 4 different markers created in random locations[1]]

Here you are the method I use to spawn 5 different markers (in my code they are the enemies):

```
public void spawnEnemies(Location location){
   Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        enemies[i] = new Enemy("Name", 0, location);
        markerOptions= new MarkerOptions().position(enemies[i].position).title("Monster" + enemies[i].name).snippet("Level" + enemies[i].livello + "\n" + enemies[i].printHealth());
        circleOptions= new CircleOptions().center(nemici[i].position).radius(nemici[i].radius).fillColor(color).strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(8);
        enemies[i].marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
        enemies[i].circle = map.addCircle(circleOptions);

        quantityOfEnemies++;

    }
}
```

Is there any method to add objects below markers? 
Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: But does framelayout stay underneath the marker even if I zoom in and out or I move the camera?

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena could you please add some sample code please? I don't know how to do this. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena I'm really sorry but I still don't understand how could I use that for my purpose. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I have updated my answer for further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand the Google APIs for Android Maps first:

[Google Map APIs](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/unit-4-add-geo-features-to-your-apps/lesson-9-mapping/9-1-c-google-maps-api/9-1-c-google-maps-api.html)

and

[Maps With Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker)

Please see that you can overlay the map objects using this reference:

[Map Objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#mapobject)

Please go through this documentation after you follow the above:

[Ground Overlays on Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/groundoverlay)

I think you should go through complete tutorial.

You need to understand the concept of tiles as well.

[Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay)

> Now what `Uber` does is, it keeps two `Layout groups`, one to show the
>   map, and the other one (`FrameLayout`) to toggle between animated
>   `ImageView` with a static `ImageView`, while the map is dragged and
>   stopped. But these ImageViews stay in their place. So you have to take
>   `Map Objects` that overlay on it and move along. In one of the objects
>   you can place progress bar.

Happy Coding :-).

Comment: Thank you very much